# How to use 'filetype indent on', without it indenting while entering text in insert mode

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I'm using `filetype indent on` in my vimrc, generally this works very well, when pressing return it sets the indentation properly (in most cases).

However it has a very strange/annoying behavior, of re-indenting a line, when editing some text to that line.
eg, editing a `CMakeLists.txt`, typing `endif(` will re-indent the the line based on vims indentation logic (in other cases too, this is just an example).

Is there a way to enable `filetype indent` when adding in new-lines, but not have it attempt to re-indent existing text while typing?

Comment: In addition to `filetype indent`, the settings of `fo` (formatoption) modifies vims indent behaviour. I would check the settings with `:set fo?`

Comment: I'm curious: Is there a reason why you have not marked my answer as correct? Perhaps I am wrong (I do not think so)?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the indent behaviour through the option [`indentkeys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'indentkeys'). The docs explain things relatively well:

> A list of keys that, when typed in Insert mode, cause reindenting of
>       the current line.  Only happens if 'indentexpr' isn't empty.
>       The format is identical to 'cinkeys', see |indentkeys-format|.

If you do: `:echo &indentkeys`, you will see that the filetype plugin for `cmake` adds for instance `ENDIF(`. Thus you might want to do something like:

```
set indentkeys&
```

To reset the option to its default value. Note that this should come in `$VIM/after/ftplugin/cmake.vim` (or similar) so that it is sourced after the regular filetype plugin.